# Is it possible to change a python path for a virtual environment getting from github?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

After a git clone in my Visual Studio Code, I have a virtual environment.
I have runned the activate script, but when I want to run the server with my command :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I have an error about the python path:

```
*No Python at 'C:\Users\B\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe'*
```

which is obviously the path of the original computer which has created the project.

Is there a way to redirect this path in my virtual environment or to change the python interpreter for this project ? It doesn't change with the command palette/Python:select interpreter.

Comment: Virtual environments should not be exchanged between different machines. Create a new one.

Comment: did the repo owner commit the virtual environment, so you have Tensorflow, Matplotlib, SKlearn, Pandas pre installed by cloning the repo. That person needs to take a git workshop

Comment: Yeah I kinda agree about the git workshop

Answer (score 1):

I changed the file :

```
.venv/pyvenv.cfg
```

Inside I modified this variable

```
home = C:\Python39
```

it works for me (at least django has started)

Comment: This could have disastrous consequences. The repo creator shouldn't have committed their virtual environment. The only thing needed was a `requirements.txt` file for package and dependency management.